# generalized normal distribution with additional kurtosis parameter

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am looking for a generalized normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ but with an additional parameter for the kurtosis to add fat-tails. I can't find it - can anybody help?

Comment: Depends how you want to generalize, but for instance the [Student t distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%E2%80%99s_t-distribution) becomes the standard normal distribution for high degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Ideally I want to let the parameters for mean and variance stay the same but having an additional parameter for kurtosis.

Comment: That's can be obtained with any distribution with at minimum two free parameters. Just relabel the parameters so that the mean and variance are $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. Your constraints are too weak to give anything interesting.

Comment: I cannot follow: The other constraint is that when the third parameter is e.g. 3 (or 0) we are back to the normal distr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Pearson type VII distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution) might be what your are looking for. You will need to reparametrize it, but wikipedia page has the necessary formulas.

Comment: this was really very helpful - Thank you. Do you know if there is also a log-pearson type vii distribution? I can't find any references in google...

Comment: @vonjd, you're welcome. Thank helpful people who mentioned this distribution in kurtosis wikipedia page, that is how I found it. If by log-pearson you mean distribution of random variable whose log is pearson VII, you can derive its distribution function similarly to log-normal. Hence no readily available references.